# Packaging JOGL into fat JAR

Tags: java, opengl, gradle, jar, processing

I use Processing in my Java 8 application, and it works well on IntelliJ. The problem occurs after Gradle exports the fat jar (code below) packaging dependencies for all platform:

```
jar {
    baseName = applicationName
    version = actualVersion
    manifest { attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Whenever i try to open the window extending PApplet, it raises this exception:

> com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Profiles [GL4bc, GL4, GL3bc, GL3, GLES3, GL2, GLES2] not available on device WindowsGraphicsDevice[type .windows, connection decon, unitID 0, handle 0x0, owner false, NullToolkitLock[obj 0x76dc78af]]
>   at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:1039)
>   at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:1050)
>   at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.getMaxProgrammable(GLProfile.java:826)
>   at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL.initGL(PSurfaceJOGL.java:203)
>   at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL.initFrame(PSurfaceJOGL.java:136)
>   at processing.core.PApplet.initSurface(PApplet.java:10877)
>   at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10764)
>   at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10501)
>   at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10483)

Here are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.processing:core:3.3.5'
    compile 'org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2'
    compile 'org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.3.2'
    testCompile 'org.json:json:20180130'
    compile files('libs/proscene.jar', 'libs/controlP5.jar')

    runtime "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.3.2:natives-macosx-universal"
    runtime "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.3.2:natives-windows-amd64"
    runtime "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.3.2:natives-windows-i586"

    runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2:natives-macosx-universal"
    // runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2:natives-solaris-i586"
    runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2:natives-windows-amd64"
    runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2:natives-windows-i586"

    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0',
            'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.1.0')
    testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0',
            'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.1.0')
}
```

Digging around the processing and JOGL forum does not help much. What should i do?

P/S: one weird thing is exporting fat jar by Eclipse will somehow make the jogl in jar runnable.

Comment: This probably has something to do with how JOGL handles its native dependencies. If I were you I'd start by comparing the contents of the two jar files. Does the Eclipse version contain any files that the Intellij version does not?

Comment: I already compare those two. Quite confusing as Eclipse also packs up test classes. But it seems the Eclipse package contains **jogamp\nativetag\opengl\** which does not appear in Gradle export package.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like you want to include those in your Intellij jar. I'm not exactly sure how to do that, but at least you have a place to start your googling.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like i found solution. I used [shadow](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow) which helps bundling all dependencies into an executable fat jar. Now JOGL works fine.